# upload single file to s3 via travis instead of directory

Tags: amazon-s3, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to upload a file to S3 Bucket via travis. However I am not able to do that. Here is the snippet below.

```
deploy:
  - provider: s3

bucket: test-S#
region: eu-west-1
upload-dir: test-s2/application
local-dir: target/latest.tar.gz
skip_cleanup: true
```

The error I am getting is `Not a directory - target/latest.tar.gz`. I want to know how can I upload a single file instead of whole directory to S3 with Travis. Is there any way for that?

Comment: Move `latest.tar.gz` to sth like `target/latest` and `local-dir: target/latest`, maybe?

Comment: @набиячлэвэли that seems to be the answer for this

Answer (score 0):

To upload a single file, We need to perform one extra step here. Use `before_deploy` stage to achieve it.

```
before_deploy
  - cp -Rf YOUR_FILE_LOCATION file_name.tar.gz
```

Now, Instead of specifying the local directory, use `glob` option from the `s3` provider.

Please see below example.

```
deploy:
  - provider: s3
    bucket: bucket_name
    region: us-east-2
    skip_cleanup: true
    upload-dir: 's3_upload_directory'
    glob: 'file_name.tar.gz'
```

At the end, your travis file will look like as below.

```
before_deploy
  - cp -Rf YOUR_FILE_LOCATION file_name.tar.gz
deploy:
  - provider: s3
    bucket: bucket_name
    region: us-east-2
    skip_cleanup: true
    upload-dir: 's3_upload_directory'
    glob: 'file_name.tar.gz'
```